# iPhone - Wakeup my App Window

Tags: objective-c, ios5

My app runs in the background. Upon some info arriving I need to wake it up  - bring up the display.
How to do it?

Thanks,
Nahum

Comment: [This may be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/search).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at either a Local "Scheduled" notification or a "Push Notification" some more here.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Urban Airship http://urbanairship.com/ I think offer a free service up to some limit for push notifications which should work fine.
Or Parse.com does something similar if you dont wont to roll your own push notification server.
If you ever get a million downloads you will be rolling in cash and you wont have to worry about a few hundred bucks / month.

Comment: Thanks. I would rather open a regular window. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry you cannot. There are no apps today that do this. And you cannot do this. You will need to use a push notification or local notification to alert the user that something has happened. You app cannot magically wake up.

Comment: Why, magically opening can only in Jailbreaked devices from Veency app

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions:

1) You can send a Push Notification. And user must just slide, and your app will open

2) if your iOS device is Jailbreaked, then in Cydia exist a Veency app. Maybe [him](http://www.simonblog.com/2008/10/19/how-to-use-veency-to-remote-control-your-iphone/) will help to you